# Messaging: The notification permission was not granted and blocked instead

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

Firebase messaging error in https server.

`An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: The notification permission was not granted and blocked instead. (messaging/permission-blocked).`

What should I do to get my token? 
On localhost, it's working.

Here is my code:

`firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```
// Import and configure the Firebase SDK
// These scripts are made available when the app is served or deployed on Firebase Hosting
// If you do not serve/host your project using Firebase Hosting see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-app.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-messaging.js")


// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: apiKey,
  authDomain: authDomain,
  databaseURL: databaseURL,
  projectId: projectId,
  storageBucket: storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: messagingSenderId,
  appId: appId,
  measurementId: measurementId
};


// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
/**
 * Here is is the code snippet to initialize Firebase Messaging in the Service
 * Worker when your app is not hosted on Firebase Hosting.
 // [START initialize_firebase_in_sw]
 // Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
 // Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
 // are not available in the service worker.
 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');
 // Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
 // messagingSenderId.
 firebase.initializeApp({
   'messagingSenderId': 'YOUR-SENDER-ID'
 });
 // Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
 // messages.
 const messaging = firebase.messaging();
 // [END initialize_firebase_in_sw]
 **/

// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the
// background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should
// implement this optional method.
// [START background_handler]

// [END background_handler]

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

`footer.blade.php`
in //script// section:

```
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: apiKey,
  authDomain: authDomain,
  databaseURL: databaseURL,
  projectId: projectId,
  storageBucket: storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: messagingSenderId,
  appId: appId,
  measurementId: measurementId
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const tokenDivId = 'token_div';
  const permissionDivId = 'permission_div';

  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.usePublicVapidKey('BKotWNDl7JOuYb-UeusSlSl47onAFH9sWJ_M1WDivsjWq0AZWah5LjVfBAxbcS8T8Yo10HEw_xPX68kMnzTQC2k');

  // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
  // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
  messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
    if (currentToken) {

      sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
      updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
    } else {
      // Show permission request.
      console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      // Show permission UI.
      updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
      setTokenSentToServer(false);
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
    setTokenSentToServer(false);
  });

  // Callback fired if Instance ID token is updated.
  messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
    messaging.getToken().then((refreshedToken) => {
      console.log('Token refreshed.');
      // Indicate that the new Instance ID token has not yet been sent to the
      // app server.
      setTokenSentToServer(false);
      // Send Instance ID token to app server.
      sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
      // ...
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
      showToken('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
    });
  });

  function resetUI() {
    clearMessages();
    showToken('loading...');
    // [START get_token]
    // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
    // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
    messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
      if (currentToken) {
        sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
        updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
      } else {
        // Show permission request.
        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        // Show permission UI.
        updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
        setTokenSentToServer(false);
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
      showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
      setTokenSentToServer(false);
    });
    // [END get_token]


  }


  function showToken(currentToken) {
    // Show token in console and UI.
    var tokenElement = document.querySelector('#token');
    tokenElement.textContent = currentToken;
  }

  // Send the Instance ID token your application server, so that it can:
  // - send messages back to this app
  // - subscribe/unsubscribe the token from topics
  function sendTokenToServer(currentToken) {
    if (!isTokenSentToServer()) {
      console.log('Sending token to server...');
      // TODO(developer): Send the current token to your server.
      setTokenSentToServer(true);
    } else {
      console.log('Token already sent to server so won\'t send it again ' +
          'unless it changes');
    }

  }

  function isTokenSentToServer() {
    return window.localStorage.getItem('sentToServer') === '1';
  }

  function setTokenSentToServer(sent) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('sentToServer', sent ? '1' : '0');
  }

  function showHideDiv(divId, show) {
    const div = document.querySelector('#' + divId);
  }

  function requestPermission() {
    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    // [START request_permission]
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
      console.log('Notification permission granted.');
      // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
      // [START_EXCLUDE]
      // In many cases once an app has been granted notification permission, it
      // should update its UI reflecting this.
      resetUI();
      // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    });
    // [END request_permission]
  }

  function deleteToken() {
    // Delete Instance ID token.
    // [START delete_token]
    messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
      messaging.deleteToken(currentToken).then(function() {
        console.log('Token deleted.');
        setTokenSentToServer(false);
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // Once token is deleted update UI.
        resetUI();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Unable to delete token. ', err);
      });
      // [END delete_token]
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
      showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
    });

  }

  // Add a message to the messages element.
  function appendMessage(payload) {
    const messagesElement = document.querySelector('#messages');
    const dataHeaderELement = document.createElement('h5');
    const dataElement = document.createElement('pre');
    dataElement.style = 'overflow-x:hidden;';
    dataHeaderELement.textContent = 'Received message:';
    dataElement.textContent = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2);
    messagesElement.appendChild(dataHeaderELement);
    messagesElement.appendChild(dataElement);
  }

  // Clear the messages element of all children.
  function clearMessages() {
    const messagesElement = document.querySelector('#messages');
    while (messagesElement.hasChildNodes()) {
      messagesElement.removeChild(messagesElement.lastChild);
    }
  }

  function updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken) {
    showHideDiv(tokenDivId, true);
    showHideDiv(permissionDivId, false);
    showToken(currentToken);
  }

  function updateUIForPushPermissionRequired() {
    showHideDiv(tokenDivId, false);
    showHideDiv(permissionDivId, true);
  }
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This indicates that you have blocked the push notifications permission on the deployed website. It's `messaging.getToken()` that is likely erroring out ([see the docs for more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token)).

If you're using Chrome, you should be able to click the lock to the left of the URL and go to "Site Settings" where you'll see a bell icon with the notification settings for the site:

[image: screenshot of Chrome notifications settings]

This may be set to "Block" and you would need to change it to "Allow" instead.

Comment: Thanks, what about firefox?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're not in an incognito tab - in that case the permissions dialog (Allow/Block) won't show up (in Chrome at least)

Comment: any solution on incognito mode?